# Save Log File in Azure

Tags: file, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, logging, azure-blob-storage

**In summary**

I want to capture this in a text file in azure

```
Console.WriteLine("Message");
```

**Long text:**

well my question today is how to save a log file in the blob storage in azure

I used to have this code and served well, but this made ​​him and kept on my local disk.

```
private string sLogFormat;
private string sErrorTime;

public CreateLogFiles()
{
    sLogFormat = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString()+" "+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString()+" ==> ";

    string sYear    = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    string sMonth    = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
    string sDay    = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
    sErrorTime = sYear+sMonth+sDay;
}

public void ErrorLog(string sPathName, string sErrMsg)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sPathName+sErrorTime,true);
    sw.WriteLine(sLogFormat + sErrMsg);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}

CreateLogFiles Err = new CreateLogFiles();
Err.ErrorLog("something/another/log","Message");
```

-- something important, all lines are generated in auxiliary applications or webjobs in my project.

but now that I want to publish my site to Azure as I can keep this up, because as I said well served.

I'm testing this method and apparently works well, the problem is that the file will be bigger each time and the process will take longer to complete.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = storageAzure //Data Access;
var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var blob = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(path).GetBlockBlobReference("log.txt"); //File
var textoriginal = blob.DownloadText(); // Download text of file
var textoadd = textoriginal + "msjError"; // add new text

blob.UploadText(textoadd.ToString()); // upload all the text
```

I hope you can guide me, to try to do this best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look to leverage the inbuilt Azure Diagnostics service which will scale much better than your existing approach (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433048.aspx).

You will need replace your Console.WriteLine statements with Diagnostics Trace statements instead (you need to add using statements and can then just replace 'Console' with 'Trace').  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd83saa2.aspx

In your application's configuration file you then need to ensure you define the appropriate Azure storage account to write the entries to - they will show up in a table typically called 'WADWindowsEventLogsTable'). See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh411534.aspx